# Cannot update user interface (Using openCV) CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opencv, user-interface

I am implementing an application with OpenCV library. After processing the inputFrame of the camera, I want to update my TextView. However, I get the following error:

```
08-01 17:01:45.085: E/AndroidRuntime(16284): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Below is simplified code of my app:

```
(...IMPORTS...)
public class ObjectTracker extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnClickListener {

TextView resultTextView;

private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                myJavaCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

public ObjectTracker() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Instantiated new " + this.getClass());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    (...)
    resultTextView = (TextView)           
    findViewById(R.id.activity_object_tracker_native_textview_result);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if (myJavaCameraView != null)
        myJavaCameraView.disableView();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_6, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (myJavaCameraView != null)
        myJavaCameraView.disableView();
}

public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
}

public void onCameraViewStopped() {
}

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    (...)
    return trackFilteredObject(filteredFrame, newInputFrame);
}

public Mat trackFilteredObject(Mat filteredFrame, Mat inputFrame)
{
    (...)

    //HERE I WANT TO UPDATE MY TEXT VIEW

    return inputImage;
}
```

}

I don't know where I should put the update code to get rid of this error. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UI stuff can only be modified from the main UI thread. And the `trackFilteredObject` method of your callback (where you update your `TextView`) is obviously called from a background thread.

To solve the issue, you can use the [Activity#runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method which lets you post a runnable to be executed on the UI thread.

Try to replace

```
//HERE I WANT TO UPDATE MY TEXT VIEW
```

By

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        //HERE I WANT TO UPDATE MY TEXT VIEW
    }
});
```

Comment: Your solution is not working. I still get same exception...Maybe the problem is in onResume() method? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
public Mat trackFilteredObject(Mat filteredFrame, Mat inputFrame)
{
    (...)

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            //HERE I UPDATE TEXT VIEW
        }
    });

    return inputImage;
}
```

Thanks for help @fiddler